# Core Data - Technique For Saving Relationships?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, relation

My data model has the following relationship:

```
[Account] -|------o< [Transaction]
```

Which is implemented as:

```
// in Account.h
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *transactions;

// in Transaction.h
@property (nonatomic, retain) Account *account;
```

Now, I've successfully created an Account and inserted it into Core Data. My question is, how do I add a starting balance to the account? It's obviously just a Transaction on the Account, but is the following sufficient to make the connection both ways (ie connect `newAccount.transactions` as well as `newTransaction.account`) in the Data Model?

```
// we need to insert a new account
Account *newAccount = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[Account entityName] inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

// . . . configure newAccount

NSNumber *startingBalance = @([self.startingBalanceTextField.text floatValue]);

NSError *error;

// save the new account
[self.managedObjectContext save:&error];

if( !error )
{
    Transaction *newTransaction = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[Transaction entityName] inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    // . . . configure newTransaction

    // is this sufficient & proper? Will this add newTransaction to newAccount.transactions as well?
    newTransaction.account = newAccount;

    // save the starting balance
    [self.managedObjectContext save:&error];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if `transactions` and `account` are defined as inverse relationships, then

```
newTransaction.account = newAccount;
```

automatically adds `newTransaction` to `newAccount.transactions`.

You can easily verify that in the debugger with `po newAccount`.